# how to make user select only a particular seat?

Tags: java, swing

I am having a problem here.. can any one provide me a suitable solution for this problem ...
The problem is, how to make sure that the user can't select a mixture of seat for example user can't select 3 right and 3 left .. but the user can select more than one seat at a time.

How can i solve this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CinemaTicketMachine {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    private JToggleButton[] seats = new JToggleButton[80];
    private JTextArea selectedSeats = new JTextArea(3, 40);

    CinemaTicketMachine() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        selectedSeats.setLineWrap(true);
        selectedSeats.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        selectedSeats.setEditable(false);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(selectedSeats), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        JPanel cinemaFloor = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(40, 0));
        cinemaFloor.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Available Seats"));
        ui.add(cinemaFloor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel leftStall = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 2, 2));
        JPanel centerStall = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4, 2, 2));
        JPanel rightStall = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 2, 2));

        cinemaFloor.add(leftStall, BorderLayout.WEST);
        cinemaFloor.add(centerStall, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cinemaFloor.add(rightStall, BorderLayout.EAST);

        ActionListener seatSelectionListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                showSelectedSeats();
            }
        };

        for (int ii=0; ii <seats.length; ii++) {
            JToggleButton tb = new JToggleButton("S-" + (ii+1));
            tb.addActionListener(seatSelectionListener);
            seats[ii] = tb;
            int colIndex = ii%8;
            if (colIndex<2) {
                leftStall.add(tb);
            } else if (colIndex<6) {
                centerStall.add(tb);
            } else {
                rightStall.add(tb);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showSelectedSeats() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int ii=0; ii<seats.length; ii++) {
            JToggleButton tb = seats[ii];
            if (tb.isSelected()) {
                sb.append(tb.getText());
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }
        String s = sb.toString();
        if (s.length()>0) {
            s = s.substring(0, s.length()-2);
        }
        selectedSeats.setText(s);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CinemaTicketMachine o = new CinemaTicketMachine();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can prevent the user from selecting an invalid combination of seats.

1. On selection of a seat you could disable all toggle buttons that now represent invalid selections (using `setEnabled(false)`). That way the user can't select invalid combinations.
2. On selection of an invalid seat you could display an error message and immediately unselect the seat.
3. On selection of an invalid seat you could automatically unselect seats that are making the current selection invalid.
4. You could allow an invalid combination to be selected but show an error message and not allow the user to submit/commit the combination until the error is resolved.